# Ubuntu on a fakeRAID

Tags: installation, raid, dmraid

How do i install Ubuntu alongside windows and if possible on the second drive of a computer with fakeRAID (im new to linux so if you got answers please keep them simple)

Additional info:
i am on RAID 0
My pc is pretty new and highend

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: Don't use fakeRAID, especially not RAID-0. SSDs are fast enough and HDDs won't achieve SSD-like performance in RAID-0. You're just going to shred you data.

---

Topic seems to be answered in the Community Help Wiki: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto

Comment: Well how do i "dont use fakeRAID" is int it built into your computer? and im going to switch to raid 1. i read that wiki already and the installation is not working for me i have like 13 options all /dev/mapper/random_op(1-4) and anyways i cannot install ubuntu to anyvof them anyway since it says something about  root dir not accessible or somthing.

Comment: JBOD + Software RAID